# client wants a "disaster" weather tracker on website.. possible?

Tags: weather

Hey guys, I have a client who wants their front site to have a tracker on disaster weather like hurricanes when they occur.  Essentially they want a way to manage this without getting a developer to do it everytime a new storm develops.

I know there are plenty of ways to get a weather updates on website when you have a set location.. thats easy.  Its different when you dont know the storms in advance!  Location would be different every time.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: First, are you talking about the US?  Second, have you looked at the http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/?  It seems like they provide all the data you could want.  What more do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably monitor an RSS feed.

TWC has some nice RSS feeds setup that look like they will facilitate your needs: http://www.weather.com/weather/rss/subscription/

The National Hurricane Center also has RSS feeds: http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/aboutrss.shtml